# IRC server is being stored data in DB such as mysql or psql

Tags: daemon, irc

I need a IRC server with the following features:

1. Can be store chatted data in a db such as mariadb or psql
2. Can be limit per user (rw,ro)
3. Be Freesoftware

Please suggest me.

Comment: What about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_daemons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With same circumstances, you need to a TS6 support protocol, [InspIRCd](http://www.inspircd.org/) supports everythings you need.